# jQuery regex - cannot replace break/new line to <br> in img tag' s title attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, newline

I wrote a lot of `img` tags containing `title` attribute. And I want to remove and append the `title` in a `div` tag after the `img` using jQuery. The `title` contains break/new line so when jQuery appends the `title` to HTML, that break/new line shows a white space.

I tried servel codes with regex but I still cannot replace break/new line to `<br>`:

1. `$.title.replace(/\r/, "<br />");`
2. `$.title.replace(/\n/, "<br />");`
3. `$.title.replace(/\r\n/, "<br />");`
4. `$.title.replace(/\\r\\n/, "<br />");`
5. `$.title.replace(/\\r/, "<br />");`
6. `$.title.replace(/\\n/, "<br />");`
7. `$.title.replace(" ", "<br />");`
8. `$.title.replace("&#x20;", "<br />");`
9. `$.title.replace("&#x0D;&#x0A;", "<br />");`

jsfiddle:

```js
$.title = $(".abc").attr('title');
alert($.title);

//not working
$.title.replace(/\r\n/, "<br />");


alert($.title);
$(".abc").after("<div>" + $.title + "</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="abc" title="abc
def" />
```

Comment: You should avoid to bind variables to the $. Instead use var to init a variable. so `var title = $('.abc').attr('title')`

Comment: And the regex is not the problem. You have to store your title with the replaced symbols: `$.title = $.title.replace(/\r\n/, "<br />");`

Comment: @MartinCup, I tried your method but no luck, it still does not work. Code: `var title = $('.abc').attr('title');`, `title.replace(/\r\n/, "<br />");`.

Comment: @MartinCup, I tried `$.title = $.title.replace(/\r\n/, "<br />");` either, it still shows a white space.

Comment: Ah, I found the problem, regex should find `\n` and the result should be stored back to `$.title`. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad you found it out. Please still consider not binding your variables to the $.

Answer (score 1):

The replace() method searches a string for a specified value, or a regular expression, and returns a new string where the specified values are replaced.

So you will have to assign this new string to your $.title

Try like this.

```js
$.title = $(".abc").attr('title');
alert($.title);

//working
$.title = $.title.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"<br />");


alert($.title);
$(".abc").after("<div>" + $.title + "</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="abc" title="abc
def" />
```